X11 is not working in my Cygwin installation
I had Cygwin working on my Win11 laptop for a long time.  I mostly use Emacs, running in a graphical window, not in a mintty.  I had to get my laptop reimaged for various reasons.  I had backed up my entire cygwin64 directory, but when I tried to restore it, I discovered that symlinks were broken.  I had later heard that there might be a way to fix those, but before that I had renamed my cygwin64 directory and started to reinstall Cygwin.  After many hours, it appeared to complete.  I then copied in my backed-up cygwin home directory and tried to run my Emacs desktop shortcut, which had worked for a long time before this.  That did nothing.
I then opened up a mintty and tried to run "emacs".  Instead of opening in a window, it opened in the mintty.  I then tried running "emacs-X11".  This also ran directly in the mintty.  When I exited that, the console said "Display :0.0 unavailable, simulating -nw".  I then tried running "startxwin", and that says "command not found".
I then tried rerunning the installer, to see if I missed the X11 category, but it seems to be all installed.
What could I be missing?

I managed to resolve this with additional X-related packages that I didn't notice I hadn't included.

Did you install Cygwin or Cygwin/X?

There's also a cygwin build of emacs, named emacs-w32 that uses a native Win API GUI interface, no X required. Unless you run other X11 apps too, might make sense to use that - I think that also has the advantage of doing copy/paste to other Windows apps as well as cygwin apps, because it's really a native Windows app.
